# vim doesn't print the header in hardcopy

Tags: printing

For some reason when I execute a `hardcopy` command `vim` doesn't print the header, only text. Here are my setting for `printoptions` as well as `printheader`

```
printoptions=left:3pc,number:y,syntax:n,header:2
printheader=%<%f%h%m%=Page %N
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't print the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with your very own settings and I encountered no issue. If I understand the help correctly, by default Vim will use A4 as the medium size; maybe your output gets on a smaller medium size than A4? Could you try to add something like:  `paper:letter` in your `printoptions`. Does it change something? What exact size of medium are you using?

Comment: I think questions for further clarifications to the OP should go into comments below his question.

Comment: You are correct. I had to add a `paper:letter` option